# Jenkins Error Connecting to Visual Studio Online

Tags: tfs, jenkins, azure-devops, tee

I am running Jenkins 1.595 with the TFS plugin 3.1.1 and TEE 12.0.2

I have been running jobs on Jenkins with Visual Studio Online for some time without issue, but I recently modified an existing job to point at a new branch and it stopped working.  After much troubleshooting, I decided to stand up a brand new instance.

Right now in the new instance, I am getting the same error that I was getting in the old broken job.

**An error occurred: TF14045: The identity grobocop is not a recognized identity.**

*(grobocop is an alternate credential associated to my MSDN account)*

Looking at the command Jenkins is sending, I noticed that the workspace owner is specified after the workspace name which should not be a problem.

> $ C:\TEE-CLC-12.0.2\tf.cmd workspace -new "Stage Author-MASTER;grobocop" -noprompt
>   -server:https://XXXXX.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection ********

Running this same command in the command line produces the same error, but without the workspace owner, I get the prompts for username/password and the workspace is created.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here?

Comment: Thanks for fixing the brand name mistake.  Do you have any ideas why including the workspace owner (alt credential) results in identity not recognized error?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and migrate all your code to GIT if you can.  TFS does not play happily with others.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend either dropping grobocop from the argument to new or you need to fully qualify it - grobocop@whatever.com. Grobocop by itself won't be accepted as the identity.